# convert specific properties of object to an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

This is my original Object:

```
Data = {
  aesthetic: {
    heritage: 'aesthetic',
    description: 'sdokjosk',
    value: 5
  },
  architectural: {
    heritage: 'architectural',
    description: 'doodsjdj',
    value: 1
  },
  historical: {
    heritage: 'historical',
    description: 'dcnsdlnckdjsncksdjbk kjdsbcjisdc hsdk chjsd cjhds ',
    value: 4
  },
  score: 3
};
```

i want to write a function that goes through the object and converts the properties only with 'heritage' 'description' and 'value' into an array that would look like this:

```
 [{
    "heritage": "aesthetic",
    "description": "sdokjosk",
    "value": 5
 },
  {
    "heritage": "architectural",
    "description": "doodsjdj",
    "value": 1
  },
  {
    "heritage": "historical",
    "description": "dcnsdlnckdjsncksdjbk kjdsbcjisdc hsdk chjsd cjhds ",
    "value": 4
  }
]
```

This is what I have tried:

`Object.values(Data)` 
but this returns an array with the 3 from the score property at the end

Comment: Do you want object with 3 properties specified or do you just want to rule out `value` key from consideration?

Comment: "i want to write a function" - what's stopping you?

Comment: Post your own effort.

Comment: @vibhor1997a i have.

Comment: @NikhilAggarwal no there will be more than 3 properties the main thing is getting rid of the score property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[`Object.values()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)** to get the `array` of values, then filter only objects from it using **[`Array#filter()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)**.

This is how should be your code:

```
var result = Object.values(Data).filter(x => typeof x == 'object');
```

**Demo:**

This is a working demo snippet:

```js
var Data = {
  aesthetic: {
    heritage: 'aesthetic',
    description: 'sdokjosk',
    value: 5
  },
  architectural: {
    heritage: 'architectural',
    description: 'doodsjdj',
    value: 1
  },
  historical: {
    heritage: 'historical',
    description: 'dcnsdlnckdjsncksdjbk kjdsbcjisdc hsdk chjsd cjhds ',
    value: 4
  },
  score: 3
};

var result = Object.values(Data).filter(x => typeof x == 'object');
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check all the keys you mentioned should present you can go with this :

```
Object.values(Data).filter(function(data){return data["heritage"] && data["description"] && data["value"]})
```